# microsoft dynamics crm 2011 and php

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I was assigned to a totally new task and I dont know where to start (well I started here and google of course)
Basically I need to send contact information from my website (web form) and insert the data into the  leads contacts information in microsoft dynamics crm 2011.

Does anyone know how to connect using PHP? I heard is possible with nusoap PHP library but first I want to heart suggestions from all of you, any ideas, links help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to create a really light .net web service to interact with.  This will allow you the most flexibility in the long run if you want to use more PHP/CRM 2011 interaction.

Alternatively, this works well for on-premise environments: http://phpmscrm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation, and spent lots of my resources.
The main problem is that MS Dynamics CRM 2011 is using different authentication logic according to the deployment method of the CRM system.

The solutions that I found are as follows:

1. On-Promise:

   - [PHP MSCRM](http://phpmscrm.codeplex.com/) from Paul's answer is working fine [tested].
   - [php-dynamics-crm-2011](http://code.google.com/p/php-dynamics-crm-2011/)
2. CRM Online:

   - [PHP-Dynamics-Online-CRM-2011-SOAP-Class](https://github.com/Ben-Speakman/PHP-Dynamics-Online-CRM-2011-SOAP-Class) is one of options for online CRM.
   - [PHP2CRMOnline](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23416) is an sample resource of Dynamics CRM 2011 Developer Training Kit.
      You can find it from `<extract path>/Labs/CRMOnlinefromPHP`.
3. Internet-facing deployment (IFD):

   - The solution for this authentication method is hard to find.
      Following article might give you an clue of this issue.
      [Connect to Microsoft Dynamics Crm 4.0 web service from PHP using IFD authentication](http://www.zenithies.org/articles/1/connect-to-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-web-service-from-php-using-ifd-authentication.html)
   - php-dynamics-crm-2011 is also considering the same [issue](http://code.google.com/p/php-dynamics-crm-2011/issues/detail?id=2), but is still not working for our hosted CRM.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this, we've just released https://bitbucket.org/6dg/dynamics-crm-php-connector/. Thanks

Comment: @AlanHollis Thank you for your great work. I successed to connect our hosted CRM with your library. It is using ADFS based authentication, so is needed some changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same situation a long time ago. The information I needed was kept in a MySQL database. For me the solutions was polling that database on a timely interval. If there is no database available I suggest that you create on (SQLite is a ligthweight and very usable).

Comment: Hi Bokkie, I didn't understand your solution, I have a database with the data I need to send to MS Dynamics but how can I send that date to MS dynamics?

Answer (score 0):

I created a basic library to connect to the online version of Dynamics 2011 here:

https://github.com/Ben-Speakman/PHP-Dynamics-Online-CRM-2011-SOAP-Class

Comment: Hi, I saw your website when I was trying to make this thing work. I implemented but no success for me. I haven't created the connection yet, I will try again tomorrow, Thanks.