# Is there a Python library to access Dynamics CRM?

Tags: python, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm looking for a library to work with Dynamics CRM from Python. I saw this answer regarding PHP: [microsoft dynamics crm 2011 and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993169/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-and-php)

I wonder if thre is something similar in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that:

http://pastebin.com/JevEm6j2

?

Comment: Not really. This is direct access with SOAP. I was looking for a wrapper which makes all the access easier. I guess there isn't one.

Comment: @Alon Catz have you found anything? I am working on something similar now and it is so frustrating.

Comment: No I haven't. Just crafting XML statements like a caveman