# Dynamics CRM 2011, Active Directory, SOAP, PHP

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have been connecting to Dynamics CRM 2011 Online using SOAP so that I may create a connection to a PHP based CMS.

I have managed to get Office 365 and Windows live authentication sorted as well as the various functions I require. The one thing that remains is connecting using Active Directory.

The soaplogger provided in the CRM SDK is great for figuring out the functions however it doesn't seem to help with getting the Authentication sorted. What is the easiest way to get the SOAP messages for this? Fiddler doesn't seem to provide this authentication SOAP either (however my Fiddler skills are minimal at best)

This seems to be the closest I can find however this is for CRM 4 and I don't want to use this as it won't work in CRM 2013.

http://www.zenithies.org/articles/1/connect-to-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-web-service-from-php-using-ifd-authentication.html

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamics CRM PHP Connector](https://bitbucket.org/6dg/dynamics-crm-php-connector/overview) might help you to solve authentication issue on CRM using ADFS. I haven't tested because I don't have this type environment. However the source code of this project is worth to have a look.

Also see my other answer from [microsoft dynamics crm 2011 and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993169/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-and-php/14740018#14740018)