# MS Dynamics CRM access through PHP API

Tags: php, api, dynamics-crm

I need to authenticate and perform CURD operations in MS Dynamics CRM using PHP API.

I have referred [Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993169/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-and-php/14740018#14740018) [Reference2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynamics/crm/mt149065.aspx#_Create_new_Azure_subscription) [Reference3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309638.aspx) [Reference4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm/webapipreview.aspx)

and using the below steps:

```
settings > 
Administration > 
system settings >
previews > 
accept terms & conditions > 
Web API Developer Preview  >
Enable Dynamics CRM Web API Preview to yes
```

which is given in `Reference4` link.

When I access,

`https://<your organization name>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/contacts`

and

`https://<your organization name>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/accounts`

I can get all my contacts and accounts.

But now I want to access it through php using api,

1. How to send the request for contacts and accounts?
2. How to create an application using AAD for trail version without providing credit card details?

I tried the below code:

```
$ZDURL= 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/dynamics/';    
curlWrap("GET",$ZDURL); 
function curlWrap($action,$ZDURL)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    /* $data = array('accountType' => 'MICROSOFT DYNAMICS',
            'id' => '83261c03-3a21-4c64-b62c-00d6c2127c64',
            'source'=>'PHI-cUrl-Example',
            'service'=>'lh2'); */

    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ZDURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    if($output===false)
    {
        echo "curl error >> ".curl_error($ch);
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Curl error occurs";
        echo "<pre>";print_r($output);
    }
    exit;
    curl_close($ch);
    $decoded = json_decode($output);

    return $decoded;
}
```

It shows as below:

[image]

Finally, got this [Query Data using the Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx) link, but no idea how to pass the request using php.

Need a help to retrieve CRM details by using api.

Comment: Enhanced formatting for the question

Comment: Try AlexaCRM is best https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit ... and problem authenticate is complicated

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a comprehensive tutorial on connecting to Office365 rest api's from PHP. For the new CRM 2016 / CRM 2015 WebApi preview, the workings are the same, only the endpoint and the query is different.

https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php

As for issue number 2, if you go through the azure portal, you need a credit card. You might want to check out the new Office365 app registration portal http://dev.office.com/app-registration. I don't know for sure if it supports Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Yes you are right.Even though i tested using `http://dev.office.com/app-registration` link and accessed using that app id and secret id,But no response.

Comment: Were you able to add permissions to CRM for the app?

Comment: Actually we need Azure account for creating an app for MS Dynamics.But they are asking credit card details.So I could not proceed further.