# Access web api using access token in MS Dynamics using php

Tags: php, api, azure, microsoft-dynamics

For [Previous question about Azure account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127776/ms-dynamics-crm-access-through-php-api), I can create an app using azure account.

Now I can get auth code from below url:
[Auth_code](https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=4df5de0c-3172-4a2c-96ab-e48b0f8af9ff&redirect_uri=https://XXXX/authorize.php&response_type=code)

From Auth_code we can get the access token by:

```
  $auth_code = $_GET['code'];
  $result = access($auth_code);


   function access($auth_code){
        $redirectUri = 'https://XXXX /authorize.php';


    $token_request_data = array (
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "code" => $auth_code,
    "redirect_uri" => $redirectUri,
    "client_id" => "client_id",
    "client_secret" => "client_secret",
    "resource" =>"resource" (From manifest in azure)
  );


  $token_request_body = http_build_query ( $token_request_data );


   $curl = curl_init ( 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token' );
   curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
   curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
   curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $token_request_body );
   curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

    $response = curl_exec ( $curl );

    $res = json_decode($response);
    curl_close ( $curl );
```

Now I'm trying to access the web api using that access_token,I couldn't get the result.
For example:

```
 $authHeader = 'Authorization:Bearer access_toke';
 $ch = curl_init();
 $url = 'https://domain/api/data/v8.0/contacts';
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authHeader, 'Content-  Type:application/json'));
 $result = curl_exec($curl);
  echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
 curl_close($curl);
```

I'm getting empty response. Now I have to know how to access the web API using access token.

When I try to run manually `https://domain/api/data/v8.0/contacts`, I can get all contacts in my crm.But when I try to access it by access_token using php,it returns empty.

**Web api reference url** : [reference for web api url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt607871.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the guide [Compose HTTP requests and handle errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334391.aspx#bkmk_headers), as the requirements shown at **HTTP headers** section:

> Every request should include the Accept header value of application/json, even when no response body is expected.

And there are supernumerary blank in your PHP script at `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authHeader, 'Content-  Type:application/json'));`
You can remove the blanks in `Content-Type` and try again.

By the way, you can leverage Fiddler to capture the requests from your PHP client. We you get the response body content and request status code via the tool. We can match the status code with the list at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334391.aspx#bkmk_statusCodes. If the code is always 200 without response body, you may check your code in web api.