# Can I use “Dynamics CRM PHP Connector” library for Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Tags: php, rest, soap, dynamics-crm

Is "Dynamics CRM PHP Connector" library created to make a connection with Microsoft Dynamics CRM? OR it is just a library to connect to PHP sources?

If it can get connected to Microsoft Dynamics CRM, How? Could you help me in detail? Because the basic help exists but I want a complete documentation.

I don't know the structure of Microsoft Dynamics CRM, so I asked if it can be used by ReST actions or I must use SOAP only? I want to create a form for example in my website, and then when I click submit in my site, I want it to be added to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Database too. So there are two approaches: 1. To use SOAP 2. to use ReST. Can I use ReST or not? I have searched and have found out that in order to send data to database in CRM, I must write bunch of code in PHP. So I decided to use some library like "Dynamics CRM PHP Connector", but its documentation is partial. Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Dynamics CRM access through PHP API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127776/ms-dynamics-crm-access-through-php-api). Also, if you know nothing about CRM I'd suggest you buy some training, it's a *huge* topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use "Dynamics CRM PHP Connector" library for Microsoft Dynamics CRM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719132/can-i-use-dynamics-crm-php-connector-library-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm)